# Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in BackgroundTask.winmd The notification platform is unavailable

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I got this exception while try to update the badge count using the following below code

```
BadgeUpdater badgeUpdater = BadgeUpdateManager.CreateBadgeUpdaterForApplication();

// And update the badge
badgeUpdater.Update(badge);
```

Comment: Please try to test the UWP official [Notifications sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/Notifications/cs/Notifications/ScenarioPages/Badges/Local/PrimaryTile/SetBadgeNumber) to see if you still get the exception.

Comment: After checking the official code sample, if you still get exception in your code. Please provide a [mcve] and provide your OS build version and project's target/min version.

Comment: My Os build - 16299
Target version - 16299
Min version - 15063

Comment: If you use the official UWP sample to test, you still get exception?